# "Incorrect syntax near ','" for audit trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've used SQL to query information for a while, but I'm new to creating triggers. Me and a co-worker have realized that there isn't an audit trail for our local data, so I'm trying to learn to rectify that. Don't worry, that's just background -- I'm not here to ask for a guide (although any links would be helpful... it's surprising how few articles I've read that actually explain what any of their code means). This is on SQL Server 2012.

So, I think I have the code at the point where I want to start testing it, but the problem is that I get an `Incorrect syntax near ','`, on line 7 every time the trigger fires. For reference, here's the trigger:

```
   -- =============================================
-- Author:      L. LeBlanc
-- Create date: 8/6/2015
-- Description: Testing auditing functionality
-- =============================================
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[testAuditTrigger]
   ON [SalesForce].[dbo].[DistinctTest]
   FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @id uniqueidentifier,
    @changedate varchar(21),
    @op nvarchar(50),
    @cols nvarchar(max),
    @rc bigint,
    @user varchar(128),
    @act int,
    @bitcols int,
    @bit int,
    @field int,
    @char INT,
    @maxfield int,
    @fieldname varchar(128),
    @sql varchar(2000),
    @PKCols VARCHAR(1000),
    @PKSelect VARCHAR(1000),
    @auditcols int

    select @user = system_user,
    @changedate = convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 112) + ' ' + convert(varchar(12), getdate(), 114)  

    -- determine action
    if exists (select * from inserted)
    begin
        if exists (select * from deleted)
            set @act = '0' -- update
        else
            set @act = '1' -- insert
    end
    else
        set @act = '2' -- delete

        -- get list of columns
    SELECT * INTO #ins FROM inserted
    SELECT * INTO #del FROM deleted

    -- Get primary key columns for full outer join
    SELECT @PKCols = COALESCE(@PKCols + ' and', ' on') 
               + ' i.' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ' = d.' + c.COLUMN_NAME
       FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
              INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
       WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = 'DistinctTest'
       AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
       AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
       AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

    -- Get primary key select for insert
    SELECT @PKSelect = COALESCE(@PKSelect+'+','') 
       + '''<' + COLUMN_NAME 
       + '=''+convert(varchar(100),
        coalesce(i.' + COLUMN_NAME +',d.' + COLUMN_NAME + '))+''>''' 
       FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
               INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
       WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = 'DistinctTest'
       AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
       AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
       AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME


    if @act = '0'
    begin -- convert ye olde binarye to text
        set @bitcols = COLUMNS_UPDATED()
        SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME,
            COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME),
            COLUMN_NAME, 'ColumnID') AS COLUMN_ID
        FROM SalesForce.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'DistinctTest';
    end
    else
        set @cols = ''

    select @auditcols = count(*)
    from SalesForce.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'DistinctTest_Audit'

    SELECT @field = 0, 
       @maxfield = MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'DistinctTest'
    WHILE @field < @maxfield
    BEGIN
       SELECT @field = MIN(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
               WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'DistinctTest' 
               AND ORDINAL_POSITION > @field
       SELECT @bit = (@field - 1 )% @auditcols + 1 
       SELECT @bit = POWER(2,@bit - 1)
       SELECT @char = ((@field - 1) / @auditcols) + 1
       IF SUBSTRING(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),@char, 1) & @bit > 0
                                       OR @act IN ('1','2') -- insert or delete
       BEGIN
               SELECT @fieldname = COLUMN_NAME 
                       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                       WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'DistinctTest' 
                       AND ORDINAL_POSITION = @field
               SELECT @sql = CONCAT('
            insert DistinctTest.Audit (    Id, 
               Operation, 
               ColumnsModified, 
               ChangeDate, 
               ChangeUser)
            select ''', @id , ''',''' 
                , @op , ''',' , @cols
                , ',''' , @changedate , ''''
                , ',''' , @user , ''''
                , ' from #ins i full outer join #del d'
                , @PKCols
                , ' where i.' , @fieldname , ' <> d.' , @fieldname 
                , ' or (i.' , @fieldname , ' is null and  d.'
                                , @fieldname
                                , ' is not null)' 
                                , ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is not null and  d.' 
                                , @fieldname
                                , ' is null)' )
               EXEC (@sql)
       END
END

END
```

When I use `sp_helptext` on my trigger, it gives me these same results as the beginning of the trigger. I've looked at a few examples and I'm struggling to figure out what exactly makes my trigger different in this particular case. Line 7 is `ON [SalesForce].[dbo].[DistinctTest]` according to the compiler, as far as I can tell.

I also admit that I don't have that much knowledge of how the SQL compiler works, so I don't know if it's possible that "line 7" is actually a misnomer and the error was with some logic in the body of my code. However, from what I've read, `sp_helptext` produces an accurate printout of the script that the compiler is actually reading. I was hoping to not have to go through the entire trigger for this particular error, since it seems simple.

The simplicity is also what's stumped me, though -- I don't see an extra comma anywhere near line 7, and this trigger's declaration looks pretty much identical to most that I've seen elsewhere. I've also made a couple of test triggers that worked fine before, but they only fired on one type of DML operation instead of three.

Comment: It would help a lot if you would add the whole code

Comment: Sounds like a recipe for people correcting parts of the code I haven't even gotten around to testing at all yet instead of addressing the question, but if you insist...

Comment: Make sure the `variables` inside the dynamic query aren't `NULL`

Comment: Why are you making a copy of the inserted and deleted tables? That is wholly unnecessary. The reason you are getting a syntax error is because not all of your variables have been set. I didn't look past @id. It is declared but not set.

Comment: You should probably look into Change Data Capture https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx -- it's designed to capture changes in data for you.  There is also Change Data Tracking, but I don't think it would work here. Comparison here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280519(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @SeanLange See, this is what I'm talking about. "I'm" not doing anything. I don't know how a lot of this code works, and I prefer to learn things hands-on (also known as "the hard way"). I made some modifications to a script I found online using the knowledge of SQL I already had to try and make something that works. Thanks for the tip though, but why would SQL throw an incorrect syntax error when your variables aren't set?

Comment: @JiggsJedi Thanks, I'll look into that in more detail too.

Comment: It throws an error because you are building up a dynamic sql statement and when one of those isn't set it will generate an invalid statement.

Comment: @SeanLange Ooh, so you're saying it was line 7 of the *dynamic* SQL statement, not the trigger. That makes more sense now. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Well the dynamic sql is part of the trigger. To be honest this trigger could stand from a total rewrite. There seems to be a lot of inefficient code in there. It sounds like something you inherited which makes this really challenging for you.

Comment: You... could say that. I did not inherit the trigger itself but the person in charge of the implementation I'm working on was let go recently and I've only been working here for six weeks, so I'm rather clueless (not to mention, inexperienced at SQL, obviously -- I know a good portion of the concepts but as you can see much of the syntax and conventions are still lost on me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is raised because your trigger has dynamic sql and at least one of the variable is not being set prior to be included in the dynamic sql. This will end up with an invalid sql statement. If you want to see the dynamic sql you could add a print or select statement to output the contents of @SQL before you execute it. You would have to use SSMS to view this but it would help with debugging.